# php if statement with continue works the other way around as I would expect

Tags: php, continue

So I've timestamps:

1. Start: 1353441600 Cutoff: 1353736800 (start < cutoff)
2. Start: 1353790800 Cutoff: 1353736800 (start > cutoff)

I have php statement:

```
if ($eventStarted < $todaysCutoff) continue;
```

I would expect this statement to show 1 but instead it shows 2. Is this correct, and I'm not understanding something? It acts like break to me now.

```
<?php
if (tribe_is_day()) {
        $eventStarted = strtotime(tribe_get_start_date(null, false, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $eventEnded = strtotime(tribe_get_end_date(null, false, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $todaysCutoff = strtotime($current_url_date . ' 06:00:00');

            echo ' Start: ' . $eventStarted . ' Cutoff: ' . $todaysCutoff . ' End: ' . $eventEnded;

        if ($eventStarted < $todaysCutoff) continue;
} ?>
```

I'm stupid :)

Comment: Is there a loop in the code? Continue is used to skip the rest of the code in a loop and continue in the next iteration.

Comment: @PaulS yes that's it. So continue, in reality is skip?

Comment: @SandroDzneladze: No `continue` is _next_, skip would be `break`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem understood. have no more questions.

Comment: Well continue is skip the rest of the loop block and continue with the next iteration. Break would skip the rest of the loop block and break out of the loop, i.e. not continue with the loop. Continue only makes sense within a loop.

Comment: @PaulS sure, I have a while loop. all clear now ty.

Answer (score 3):

the `continue` keyword is used inside loops like for or while. Either your code does not include the loop or you are "doing it wrong (TM)". :)

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: yes I have a while loop. For my question it makes no difference. I was misunderstanding continue, as it seems to mean skip.